# IO and Future[Option] monad transformers

Tags: scala, scalaz, monad-transformers, io-monad

I'm trying to figure out how to write this piece of code in an elegant pure-functional style using scalaz7 IO and monad transformers but just can't get my head around it.

Just imagine I have this simple API:

```
def findUuid(request: Request): Option[String] = ???
def findProfile(uuid: String): Future[Option[Profile]] = redisClient.get[Profile](uuid)
```

Using this API I can easily write impure function with OptionT transformer like this:

```
val profileT = for {
  uuid <- OptionT(Future.successful(findUuid(request)))
  profile <- OptionT(findProfile(uuid))
} yield profile
val profile: Future[Option[Profile]] = profileT.run
```

As you have noticed - this function contains findProfile() with a side-effect. I want to isolate this effect inside of the IO monad and interpret outside of the pure function but don't know how to combine it all together.

```
def findProfileIO(uuid: String): IO[Future[Option[Profile]]] = IO(findProfile(uuid))

val profileT = for {
  uuid <- OptionT(Future.successful(findUuid(request)))
  profile <- OptionT(findProfileIO(uuid)) //??? how to put Option inside of the IO[Future[Option]]
} yield profile
val profile = profileT.run //how to run transformer and interpret IO with the unsafePerformIO()???
```

Any peaces of advice on how it might be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IO` is meant more for synchronous effects. `Task` is more what you want! 
See this question and answer: [What's the difference between Task and IO in Scalaz?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32266565/whats-the-difference-between-task-and-io-in-scalaz)

You can convert your `Future` to `Task` and then have an API like this:

```
def findUuid(request: Request): Option[String] = ??? 
def findProfile(uuid: String): Task[Option[Profile]] = ???
```

This works because `Task` can represent both synchronous and asynchronous operations, so `findUuid` can also be wrapped in `Task` instead of `IO`.

Then you can wrap these in `OptionT`:

```
val profileT = for {
  uuid <- OptionT(Task.now(findUuid(request)))
  profile <- OptionT(findProfileIO(uuid))
} yield profile
```

Then at the end somewhere you can run it:

```
profileT.run.attemptRun
```

Check out this link for converting Futures to Tasks and vice versa: [Scalaz Task <-> Future](http://www.andrewconner.org/scalaz-task-scala-future)

Comment: Thx @luka-jacobowitz
Have questions
* I use this code inside of my Play's Action.async, so I have to return Future[Result]. Transforming Task to scala.Future means Task termination. As soon as it's terminated Play's Action becomes sync. Do you know how to convert Task to Future without termination?
* Going further - do you consider IO Monad as a postponed computation only? if it's so does it mean that original findProfile:Future is also lazy and it's computation also postponed in ExecutionContext? In this case may be it's not necessary to wrap Future into IO - this function is already pure?

Comment: The problem with Future is that it is not lazy. It will perform any side effects that you define inside the Futures body, making it an impure function by default. See here for more on that: https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/3zofjl/why_is_future_totally_unusable/ 
My suggestion would be to use Tasks everywhere and convert to or from Future when you have to :)

Comment: thank you. Spent last night digging into Future/Task comparison, read this reddit post as well.

Answer (score 1):

End up with this piece of code, thought it might be useful for someone (Play 2.6).

Controller's method is a pure function since Task evaluation takes place outside of the controller inside of PureAction ActionBuilder. Thanks to Luka's answer!

Still struggling with new paradigm of Action composition in Play 2.6 though, but this is another story.

**FrontendController.scala:**

```
def index = PureAction.pure { request =>
  val profileOpt = (for {
    uuid <- OptionT(Task.now(request.cookies.get("uuid").map(t => uuidKey(t.value))))
    profile <- OptionT(redis.get[Profile](uuid).asTask)
  } yield profile).run
  profileOpt.map { profileOpt =>
    Logger.info(profileOpt.map(p => s"User logged in - $p").getOrElse("New user, suggesting login"))
    Ok(views.html.index(profileOpt))
  }
}
```

**Actions.scala**

Convenient action with Task resolution at the end

```
class PureAction @Inject()(parser: BodyParsers.Default)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) extends ActionBuilderImpl(parser) {
  self =>
  def pure(block: Request[AnyContent] => Task[Result]): Action[AnyContent] = composeAction(new Action[AnyContent] {
    override def parser: BodyParser[AnyContent] = self.parser
    override def executionContext: ExecutionContext = self.ec
    override def apply(request: Request[AnyContent]): Future[Result] = {
      val taskResult = block(request)
      taskResult.asFuture //End of the world lives here
    }
  })
}
```

**Converters.scala**

Task->Future and Future->Task implicit converters

```
implicit class FuturePimped[+T](root: => Future[T]) {
  import scalaz.Scalaz._
  def asTask(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Task[T] = {
    Task.async { register =>
      root.onComplete {
        case Success(v) => register(v.right)
        case Failure(ex) => register(ex.left)
      }
    }
  }
}

implicit class TaskPimped[T](root: => Task[T]) {
  import scalaz._
  val p: Promise[T] = Promise()
  def asFuture: Future[T] = {
    root.unsafePerformAsync {
      case -\/(ex) => p.failure(ex); ()
      case \/-(r) => p.success(r); ()
    }
    p.future
  }
}
```